# How to correctly use Linux "at" command to execute a shell script that runs a matlab script?

Tags: at, matlab

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/username/test.m');exit;"
```

The test.m script is a matlab script that plots a graph and saves the figure as pdf without making the figure visible. Below is the content of the test.m script:

```
   % This is a matlab script to test with *at* execution. 
   t1=[1 2 3];
   t2=[1 2 3];
   plot(t1,t2)
   set(gcf,'Visible','off')
   print('-bestfit','/home/username/image','-dpdf')
```

What I want to do is to schedule the shell script to run at certain time. Therefore I am using the "at" command as follows:

```
echo "run_matlab_script.sh" | at 15:00
```

But when the time is 15:00 , the script seems to not be executed. 
I have also tried including the path to my script, but don't get "at" to work.

I have been following the instructions in this link as well:

https://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/

Am I using "at" the correct way? Is there an alternative to schedule the execution of a script. 
When I do `source run_matlab_script.sh` the script runs without issues.

For the shell script I gave it permissions with:

```
chmod +x run_matlab_script.sh
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `run_matlab_script.sh` located on your `PATH`? can you execute it outside of `at` without prepending a relative or absolute location?

Comment: The run_matlab_script.sh is in my home directory; it runs without issues when I do: source run_matlab_script.sh (within my home directory). I am not entirely well versed in linux, I am still learning, so I apologize for any confusion in advanced.